# Error in reasoning about starlike sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am working the following problem, and I have written a proof of the following claim, for which I have found a counterexample, after the fact.

Suppose that $E \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ is open, bounded, and starlike, and $p_0$ is a center for $E$.

Is it true or false that all points $p_1$ in a small enough neighborhood of $p_0$ are also centers for $E$?

Actual answer: False. See here: [Some Topological Properties of Starlike Sets!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/784734/some-topological-properties-of-starlike-sets)

My proof that I wrote before I found this counterexample:

*Proof.*
It is true. For each $x \in E$, let $\ell_{p_0,x}$ denote the segment joining $p_0$ and $x$. Since $E$ is open, for each $q_x \in \ell_{p_0,x}$, there is some $\epsilon_{q_x} > 0$ such that $M_{\epsilon_{q_x}} q_x \subset E$. Put $\epsilon = \min\{\epsilon_{q_x} \colon \exists x \in E\ \text{and}\ q_x \in \ell_{p_0,x}\}$. Consider $M_\epsilon p_0$ and $p_1 \in M_\epsilon p_0$. For each $x \in E$, the distance between $p_1$ and the segment $\ell_{p_0, x}$ is less than $\epsilon$. Therefore for each $q_x \in \ell_{p_0, x}$, the intersection of the segment $\ell_{p_1, x}$ with each $M_{\epsilon_{q_x}}q_x$ is nonempty, so the segment $\ell_{p_1, x}$ is entirely contained in $E$. The choice of $p_1$ was arbitrary, so all points $p_1 \in M_\epsilon p_0$ are centers for $E$.
$\square$

Where did I go wrong in my reasoning? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know. Maybe the mistake is in the part of the proof that you left out, namely, why that minimum exists?

Comment: Here's a suggestion. You linked to an explicit counterexample. Why don't you apply your proof to that example and see what value of $\epsilon$ you come up with?

Comment: If $M_\epsilon y$ denotes the open $\epsilon$-ball centred at $y$, @bof’s comments pinpoint the problem: if you examine the counterexample closely, you’ll see that $$\inf\{\epsilon_{q_x}:x\in E\text{ and }q_x\in\ell_{p_0,x}\}=0\;.$$ Look at points $x$ very close to one of the four missing line segments.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott If you post your comment as an answer, I can accept that as an answer to my question.